# Error sorting nulls first MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, null, sql-order-by

My goal is to enlist all the elements from the table `cat.CAT_RUTAS` and I'm adding a type `null` to the list with the value 'Enlistar todas las rutas', So I want that the `null` value to be the first option of the result and sort the rest values in ascending.

I'm using MSSQL SERVER but when i'm trying to run this query:

```
select CATrut_iIdentificador, CATrut_vDescripcion 
from cat.CAT_Rutas 
UNION 
SELECT NULL , 'Enlistar todas las rutas'
order by CATrut_vDescripcion ASC NULLS FIRST
```

The problem is when i'm trying to add the null value to the top. Receiving the error:

**Incorrect syntax near 'NULLS'.**

Comment: `ORDER BY column NULLS FIRST` is not valid SQL Server syntax

Comment: Are you just sorting by the wrong column? In one of the comments you said you want 'Enlistar todas las rutas' first. But you are not sorting by that column. Try changing to "order by CATrut_iIdentificador"

Comment: @SeanLange, he wants to sort all the NULLs in the ID column first, and then the other columns by Description alphabetically.

Comment: OK. So it should be as simple as "order by CATrut_iIdentificador, CATrut_vDescripcion"

Comment: No, because then everything would be ordered by ID, assuming ID is unique or NULL.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another option which is simply adding a new column for sorting.

```
select CATrut_iIdentificador, CATrut_vDescripcion, 1 as SortOrder
from cat.CAT_Rutas 
UNION 
SELECT NULL , 'Enlistar todas las rutas', 0 as SortOrder
order by SortOrder, CATrut_vDescripcion
```

Comment: But what if there are NULLs in the `CATrut_iIdentificador` column?   hmm?   ; )

Comment: @TabAlleman -  I don't see in the question where that is discussed one way or the other. The question does not address this possibility in the least.

Comment: No it doesn't.  Just pointing out that it could be the case.  And even if it is, it is not clear what results would be desired in that case.

Answer (score 5):

Order first by a `CASE` expression like this:

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN CATrut_iIdentificador IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
  CATrut_vDescripcion ASC
```

Comment: All 3 answers that popped up are correct.  In my opinion, this one is the most flexible because it can be used to sort by any number of custom values/criteria.

Comment: I'm not certain that OP understands you would then follow that with another sort on `CATrut_vDescripcion`. Maybe add for clarity?

Comment: I thought `NULL` always pop up first when you sort it? Why do you need a `CASE WHEN`?

Comment: @xbb Because he wants to sort 1st by NULL in `ColumnA`, and then alphabetically by `ColumnB`.   It's not all on one column.

Comment: oh I see, ok got it.

Answer (score 2):

MS SQL Server does not support the `nulls first` clause. However, looking at the [`order by` clause documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx), you'll see that:

> Null values are treated as the lowest possible values.

So with an `asc` ordering, you don't have to do anything, the `null`s will come first anyway:

```
select CATrut_iIdentificador, CATrut_vDescripcion 
from cat.CAT_Rutas 
UNION 
SELECT NULL , 'Enlistar todas las rutas'
order by CATrut_vDescripcion ASC
```

Comment: Except that in the sample data, the Descripcion column isn't the one that can be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that `NULLS FIRST` there is no such syntax present. It should rather be

```
select CATrut_iIdentificador, CATrut_vDescripcion 
from cat.CAT_Rutas 
UNION 
SELECT NULL , 'Enlistar todas las rutas'
order by CATrut_vDescripcion
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is, that i want the 'Enlistar todas las rutas' at the top of the list, and as you can se the value is null. I want this result:

Comment: Enlistar todas las rutas 
value 1

Comment: Same problem as Mureinik's answer.   Look closely at the original query.  OP wants sorted by NULL in the ID column, and then alphabetical in the Description column.  It's not all the same column.

Comment: @TabAlleman, where is that mentioned in OP's post? I can't conclude it from this statement *So I want that the null value is the first option of the result and sort the rest values in ascending* ... can you?

Comment: @Rahul It's basically supposed to be a heading for the listing. It's not really stated in the question though.

Comment: @Rahul, I don't know what to say other than, yeah, that's how I read that sentence.   It's not perfectly clear, but if I had to start guessing exactly what that sentence meant (and I did), that's my first guess.   Well, I did also corroborate that guess with what it looks like he's trying to do in his query.

Comment: OP means that he added a null with a corresponding "value", i.e., description. He wants that null *row* to be first. The English isn't perfect but it makes sense.